# Javascript history error: Going back seems broken

Tags: javascript, history, back

I'm currently messing with the browser history with javascript, and I almost have what I want.
But I encounter one huge error, let me explain the situation:

I have a menu, and when pressing on a menu item, the following code is executed:

```
$("#content").load("http://example.com/menuitem");
window.history.pushState({ page:"http://example.com/menuitem" },"", "http://example.com/menuitem");
document.title = 'Menu item';
```

I also have an empty `onbeforeunload` function, so the browser's back, forward and history options work as expected. And I have an onpopstate function, but I don't see him doing anything, so don't know if I actually need him.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
};

window.onpopstate = function(e){
    console.log('onpopstate was called');
    if(e.state){
        window.location.href = e.state.page;
    }
};
```

Now, my huge error:
I am testing as follows:

- Type 'stackoverflow.com' in the addressbar
- Type 'example.com' in the addressbar
- Click on a menuitem
- Type 'google.com' in the addressbar
- Go back by the browser back-button, until you reach stackoverflow.com

When I go back, the first time I got on example.com/menuitem as expected, but when going back the second time, I once more got on the exact same page, instead of getting on example.com, which is what I want. From this moment, when I look in the history, my 'example.com/menuitem' page seems to be duplicated for some reason.

What goes wrong here and how can I fix my error?

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you did the test twice, and the second time, when going back, the sequence was `google -> stackoverflow` instead of `google -> example.com -> stackoverflow` ?

Comment: @Raad, No the sequence is always consequently `google -> example.com/menuitem -> example.com/menuitem -> etc.` (same page continually) while I want to following: `google -> example.com/menuitem -> example.com -> stackoverflow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, I needed to add a `.replaceState()` on the current page (example.com) before the `.pushState()`.
And move the `window.onpopstate` function to the page being called (example.com/menuitem).

```
window.history.replaceState({ page:"http://example.com/" },"", "example.com");
```

I got this answer by try and error. I hope this will help others.